# On a quandle cocycle

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

A quandle is a nonempty set $X$ on which there is defined a binary operation $(x,y) \rightarrow x*y$
satisfying the following properties.

(Q1) $x*x=x$, $\forall x \in X$.

(Q2) For any $x,y \in X$, there is a unique element $z \in X$ such that $x=z*y$.

(Q3) For any $x,y,z \in X, x*(y*z)=(x*y)*(x*z)$

Let $X$ be a finite quandle, and $G$ be
an abelian group written multiplicatively. A map $\theta:X \times X \times X \rightarrow G$ is called a
$3$-cocycle of $X$ with the coefficient group $G$ if it satisfies the following two conditions:

(i) $\theta(x,x,y)=\theta(x,y,y)=1_G$, for any $x,y \in X$.

(ii) For any $x,y,z,w \in X$

$\theta(x,z,w)-\theta(x,y,w)+\theta(x,y,z)=\theta(x*y,z,w)-\theta(x*z,y*z,w)+\theta(x*w,y*w,z*w)$

My question is the following:
Suppose $x*z_1=x*z_2=x$ and $y*z_1=y*z_2=y$, where $x,y,z_1,z_2$ are distinct elements in the quandle $X$. Then is the following equation true

$\theta(x,y,z_1)=\theta(x,y,z_2)$?

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: yes, sorry for this confusing notation.

Comment: Are you sure you have Q3 going in the correct direction? Not $(x*y)*z=(x*z)*(y*z)$?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the answer is no. Take the trivial quandle $ x*y=x \,\,\,\,\forall x,y$, then the (second) cocycle condition is trivial, you should get a counter example with the trivial quandle on 3 elements